# no module named pyrebase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase

i have been trying to access my firebase DB through a python program on my rapberry pi 3, but i have been encountering the same import error

```
File "/home/pi/Desktop/testFB.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyrebase
ImportError: No module named 'pyrebase'
```

Here is the code

```
 import pyrebase

    config = {
      "apiKey": "apikey",
      "authDomain": "db.firebaseapp.com",
      "databaseURL": "https://db.firebaseio.com/",
      "storageBucket": "db.appspot.com"
    }
firebase = Pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db=firebase.database()
print(db.get())
```

upon running 'pip3 list', 'Pyrebase==3.0.27' is in there

but in the file /usr/lib/python3.5 (where the rest of my modules are) Pyrebase.py is not there?

any help is appreciated, although similar questions have solutions that have not been working for me...
thanks in advance,
3NiGMa

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? (python2, python3).

Comment: i do, should i uninstall  python 2.x?

Comment: If you don't need it you can uninstall it to make things less complicated, but it is easier to use `virtualenv` to create a clean env for your current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either not installed the module or the path where the module is installed is not included in your current python PATH.

I recommend to use pip to install all modules.

```
pip install pyrebase
```

You can show your include paths with:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

Can you find your pyrebase folder in those paths? If not something is wrong with your config.

I also recommend that you use `virtualenv`, for more information see https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ as you can choose python interpreter version and depedencies for every project and you don't have to mix modules needed by other projects. It also always creates a clean state for a new project.

Comment: thanks, Frieder, but i have already installed it using pip and pip3, issue still persists

Comment: I updated my answer, as I didn't see your `pip3 list` output or you edited it in.

Comment: You should start with a clean env for your project by using virtualenv. Otherwise it is hard to tell what your problem is, especially if you are using multiple python versions and you are mixing modules installed by our OS (system wide) and modules installed by pip (system and/or user).

Comment: after a file search i found it under python 2.7, however i am using python 3.6, is this the source of my issue?

Comment: ok, i copied pyrebase.py from python2.7 dist-packages to python 3.5, but now i have an error 'sseclient not found'? should i try the same thing again

Comment: @3NiGMa DON'T COPY modules from 2.7 to 3.x! You will break things for sure and you will be also missing all dependencies for this module. For some reason pip3 command seems to install it to 2.7 too. I would recommend to uninstall pyrebase for 2.7 and 3.x with pip and then check why pip3 is using the wrong directory. Then install pyrebase again with `pip3`

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you have a method of finding out why pip3 is installing into python2.7 directory? I have never had this issue with modules before...

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back uninstall of pycryptodome
Moving to c:\users\hitman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\crypto
from C:\Users\Hitman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages~rypto
Moving to c:\users\hitman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pycryptodome-3.9.8.dist-info
from C:\Users\Hitman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages~ycryptodome-3.9.8.dist-info